# SQL join from multiple tables

Tags: t-sql

We've got a system (MS SQL 2008 R2-based) that has a number of "input" database and a one "output" database. I'd like to write a query that will read from the output DB, and `JOIN` it to data in one of the source DB. However, the source table may be one or more individual tables :( The name of the source DB is included in the output DB; ideally, I'd like to do something like the following (pseudo-SQL ahoy)

```
select o.[UID]
      ,o.[description]
      ,i.[data]
from [output].dbo.[description] as o
    left join (select [UID]
                    ,[data]
                from
                    [output.sourcedb].dbo.datatable
                ) as i
        on i.[UID] = o.[UID];
```

Is there any way to do something like the above - "dynamically" specify the database and table to be joined on for each row in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the table must be known at the time you prepare the query.  Otherwise how would the query optimizer know what indexes it might be able to use?  Or if the table you reference even has an UID column?

You'll have to do this in stages:

1. Fetch the `sourcedb` value from your output database in one query.
2. Build an SQL query string, interpolating the value you fetched in the first query into the FROM clause of the second query.

   Be careful to check that this value contains a legitimate database name.  For instance, filter out non-alpha characters or apply a regular expression or look it up in a whitelist.  Otherwise you're exposing yourself to a [SQL Injection](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) risk.
3. Execute the new SQL string you built with `exec()` as @user353852 suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the exec function, then specify the select as a string, adding variables for database names and tables where appropriate.  Simple example:

```
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(255), @tableName VARCHAR(255), @colName VARCHAR(255)
...
EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @dbName + '.dbo.' + @tableName + ' WHERE ' + @colName + ' = 1')
```

Comment: I've never actually seen the exec function before, but there's no way something like this is appropriate. I do know that string concatenation anywhere near SQL is a bad idea.

Comment: If you are talking about injection then you are right, you would not load the values of the variables dbName etc. from user data at all.  These variables should not be populated by user data but from environmental settings. e.g. in Freds environment his database is 'fred' and in Barneys environment his database is 'barney', so te variables should be set based on that.